# How do I find the midpoint of a triangle in pygame and then recursively execute it repeatedley to make a sierpinski triangle?

Tags: python, pygame

How do I find the midpoint of a triangle that was originally drawn? I need to create a sierpinski triangle in which there are multiple triangles within a triangle. So far, I have the code for the first triangle shown below:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
colors = [pygame.Color(0, 0, 0, 255),       # Black
          pygame.Color(255, 0, 0, 255),     # Red
          pygame.Color(0, 255, 0, 255),     # Green
          pygame.Color(0, 0, 255, 255),     # Blue
          pygame.Color(255, 255, 255, 255)] # White

# Each of these constants is the index to the corresponding pygame Color object
# in the list, colors, defined above.
BLACK = 0
RED = 1
GREEN = 2
BLUE = 3
WHITE = -1



height = 640
width = 640
size = [width, height]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
screen.fill(WHITE)

def draw_triangle(p1, p2, p3, color, line_width, screen):
    p1 = [5, height - 5]
    p2 = [(width - 10) / 2, 5]
    p3 = [width - 5, height - 5]
    pygame.draw.polygon(screen, 0, [p1, p2, p3], 2)
    pygame.display.flip()

def find_midpoint(p1, p2):

def sierpinski(degree, p1, p2, p3, color, line_width, screen):
```

Both remaining functions are what are need to complete the sierpinski triangle. First, make a function to find the midpoint, then make a function that creates multiple triangles within those triangles called a sierpinski triangle.

Comment: your drawtriangle method ... will basically always draw the same triangle ... start by fixing that

Comment: yes, I have to start with a single triangle first and then the bottom two functions will draw the inner triangles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the purpose of the `degree` argument is, perhaps it's about limiting the recursive depth?

Here's an example based on your question uses a recursive sierpinski function:

```
import pygame

def draw_triangle(p1, p2, p3, color, line_width, screen):
    pygame.draw.polygon(screen, color, [p1, p2, p3], line_width)

def midpoint(p1, p2):
    """ Return the mid-point on the line p1 to p2 """
    x1, y1 = p1
    x2, y2 = p2
    x_mid = (x1 + x2) // 2
    y_mid = (y1 + y2) // 2
    return (x_mid, y_mid)

def sierpinski(degree, p1, p2, p3, color, line_width, screen):
    # p1 → bottom left, p2 → bottom right, p3 → top
    # recursive function so check for exit condition first
    if abs(p1[0] - p2[0]) <= 2 and abs(p2[0] - p3[0]) <= 2 and abs(p1[0] - p3[0]) <= 2:
        return
    draw_triangle(p1, p2, p3, color, line_width, screen)
    a = midpoint(p1, p2)
    b = midpoint(p1, p3)
    c = midpoint(p2, p3)
    # skip the centre triangle
    sierpinski(degree, p1, a, b, color, line_width, screen)
    sierpinski(degree, p2, a, c, color, line_width, screen)
    sierpinski(degree, p3, b, c, color, line_width, screen)

height = 640
width = 640
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), pygame.RESIZABLE)
pygame.display.set_caption("Sierpiński")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
update_screen = True
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
            width, height = event.dict["size"]
            screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), pygame.RESIZABLE)
            update_screen = True

    if update_screen:
        # only draw the screen when required
        screen.fill(pygame.color.Color("white"))
        # determine initial points based on window size
        p1 = [5, height - 5]
        p2 = [(width - 10) // 2, 5]
        p3 = [width - 5, height - 5]
        sierpinski(None, p1, p2, p3, pygame.color.Color("black"), 1, screen)
        pygame.display.update()
        update_screen = False
    # limit framerate
    clock.tick(30)
pygame.quit()
```

I removed your colour handling for brevity, instead using [pygame.color.Color](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/color.html#pygame.Color) which accepts string arguments to its constructor. I also used integer division `//` as a replacement for `round(…)`.

Depending on the depth or complexity of your recursive function, you could redraw every frame but I wanted to show an example of limiting in case your function complexity increases. Finally I've been playing with resizing screens recently and that seemed to tie in with a single draw so I included that as well.

[image: Sierpinski default]
[image: Sierpinski squashed]

EDIT: I've modified the `sierpinski` function to support a `degree` argument that specifies recursion dep

```
def sierpinski(degree, p1, p2, p3, color, line_width, screen):
    # p1 → bottom left, p2 → bottom right, p3 → top
    # recursive function so check for exit condition first
    if degree is None:
        if abs(p1[0] - p2[0]) <= 2 and abs(p2[0] - p3[0]) <= 2 and abs(p1[0] - p3[0]) <= 2:
            return
    else:
        if degree == 0:
            return
        else:
            degree -= 1
    …
```

Then I added some event handling so the mouse wheel could be used to increment and decrement the degree, which is shown on the title bar:

```
elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
    if event.button == 4:  # wheel up
        if degree is None:
            degree = 8
        else:
            degree += 1
            if degree > maximum_degree:
                degree = maximum_degree
        update_screen = True
    elif event.button == 5: # wheel down
        if degree is None:
            degree = 3
        else:
            degree -= 1
            if degree < minimum_degree:
                degree = minimum_degree
        update_screen = True
…
```

[image: Sierpinski animated]

Comment: I appreciate the help, yes the "degree" argument was meant to limit the number of recursions.

Answer (score 1):

The "midpoint triangle" inside another triangle is defined by a triangle who's co-ordinates are the mid-points of the sides of the surrounding triangle:

[image: midpoint triangle]

So for each line/side of your triangle, calculate the midpoint:

```
def lineMidPoint( p1, p2 ):
    """ Return the mid-point on the line p1 to p2 """
    # Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint
    x1, y1 = p1
    x2, y2 = p2
    x_mid = round( ( x1 + x2 ) / 2 )
    y_mid = round( ( y1 + y2 ) / 2 )
    return ( x_mid, y_mid )
```

In your case this would be called multiple times times with `p1`, `p2` and `p3` to generate the 3 "corner" triangles:

```
# midpoints of each size
mid_p1 = lineMidPoint( p1, p2 )
mid_p2 = lineMidPoint( p2, p3 )
mid_p3 = lineMidPoint( p3, p1 ) 

# The 3 "corner" triangles
upper_triangle = [ mid_p1, p2, mid_p2 ]
left_triangle  = [ p1, mid_p1, mid_p3 ]
right_triangle = [ mid_p3, mid_p2, p3 ]

# The inner triangle (for the sake of completeness)
inner_triangle = [ mid_p1, mid_p2, mid_p3 ]
```

You then need to wrap that in a recursive call, with some kind of depth bailout.

Something like:

```
def drawTriangle( window, colour, points, bailout=5 ):
    if ( bailout > 0 ):
        # Calculate the 3 inner corner-triangles
        p1, p2, p3 = points
        mid_p1 = lineMidPoint( p1, p2 )
        mid_p2 = lineMidPoint( p2, p3 )  # mid-point of each side
        mid_p3 = lineMidPoint( p3, p1 ) 

        # triangles between the original corners, and new mid-points
        upper_triangle = [ mid_p1, p2, mid_p2 ]  
        left_triangle  = [ p1, mid_p1, mid_p3 ]
        right_triangle = [ mid_p3, mid_p2, p3 ]

        drawTriangle( window, colour, upper_triangle, bailout-1 )
        drawTriangle( window, colour, left_triangle,  bailout-1 )
        drawTriangle( window, colour, right_triangle, bailout-1 )
    else:
        pygame.draw.lines( window, colour, True, points )  # draw triangle
```

I think that draws a [Sierpiński triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_triangle)

[image: triangle demo]

NOTE: Code presented is *not* tested, debugged code, but something quickly written to help the reader to working out a solution for themselves.